# GWT HTMLPanel + Text wrapping

Tags: html, gwt, css-float, word-wrap

I'm trying to create a HTMLPanel containing text, which also has another HTML widget floating to the right. I want to main text content to wrap around the floating HTML.

The problem is, I want to be able to change the main text content on-the-fly. At the moment I've got this:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:InlineHTML ui:field="descriptionHTML"/>
    <g:HTML ui:field="overviewHTML" styleName='{style.overview}'/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

However, GWT puts the InlineHTML contents inside a `<span>`, which doesn't wrap around the floating HTML.

So, I want to be able to change the content of `descriptionHTML` and `overviewHTML` as required, with one wrapping around the other. I assume I need to change `descriptionHTML` to be something other than an InlineHTML object, but I'm not sure what else to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a standard HTML widget instead of an InlineHTML one.

Then, play with css and float property.